# Can't access div in chrome extension using getElementById in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the text content of a div within a chrome extension's popup. However, when I try to use document.getElementById I get a 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')'

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "AAAA English Scanning",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Provides a way to quickly lookup the Japanese translation of English words",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*",
            "file://*/*"
          ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

hello.html (the default popup page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testDiv">
        Hello
    </div>
    
</body>

<script src= "content.js"></script>
</html>
```

content.js

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);

function move(e) {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;
    let coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    console.log(document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML);
    //document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = coor;
}
```

I tried waiting for the DOM to load by wrapping the addition of the content like so

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    });
```

but the above line causes the code in my 'move' function to never trigger. Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Either use two separate scripts (popup.js and content.js) for each context or remove `content_scripts` and switch to executeScript as shown in [this answer](/a/67227376).